# How to calculate percent variance due to genotypes, environments and GxE interaction in pooled ANOVA?

Tags: excel

While ascertaining stability of genotypes, how to estimate the % variation (% Total SS) due to environments, genotypes and their interaction. Can it be calculated manually (in MS Excel)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it. Just divide individual sum of squares by total sum of squares and you'll get it.